# AVAsset rotation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset

It's a well documented issue on SO, where AVAssets get rotated after writing them to file, either using `AVAssetWriter` or `AVComposition`. And there are solutions, such as looking at the video track transform and seeing how the asset is rotated so that it can be rotated to the desired orientation for your particular use case.

What I want to know however is why this happens and if it's possible to prevent it from happening. I run into issues not only with writing custom video files but also transforming videos into gifs using `CGImageDestination` where the output gif looks great except that it's rotated.

To give a quick reference point for my code that writes an asset to file:

```
let destinationURL = url ?? NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(String.random()).mp4")
        if let writer = try? AVAssetWriter(URL: destinationURL, fileType: AVFileTypeMPEG4),
            videoTrack = self.asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).last,
            firstBuffer = buffers.first {
            let videoCompressionProps = [AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: videoTrack.estimatedDataRate]
            let outputSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
                AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
                AVVideoWidthKey: width,
                AVVideoHeightKey: height,
                AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: videoCompressionProps
            ]
            let writerInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings, sourceFormatHint: (videoTrack.formatDescriptions.last as! CMFormatDescription))
            writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = false

            let rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Utils.degreesToRadians(-90))
            writerInput.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(rotateTransform, -1, 1)

            let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: writerInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)
            writer.addInput(writerInput)
            writer.startWriting()
            writer.startSessionAtSourceTime(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(firstBuffer))


            for (sample, newTimestamp) in Array(Zip2Sequence(buffers, timestamps)) {
                if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sample) {
                    while !writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData {
                        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.1)
                    }
                    pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(imageBuffer, withPresentationTime: newTimestamp)
                }
            }
            writer.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler {
              // completion code
            }
```

As you can see above, a simple transform rotates the outputted video back to portrait. However, if I have a landscape video, that transform no longer works. And as I mentioned before, transforming the video to a gif performs the exactly same 90 degrees rotation on my asset.

My feelings can be summed up in these two gifs:

http://giphy.com/gifs/jon-stewart-why-lYKvaJ8EQTzCU

http://giphy.com/gifs/the-office-no-steve-carell-12XMGIWtrHBl5e

Answer (score -3):

```
i have also find same Problem then i changed rotated my video to 90'its works fine 

Here is solution 
//in videoorientation.h 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface videoorientationViewController : UIViewController
@property AVMutableComposition *mutableComposition;
@property AVMutableVideoComposition *mutableVideoComposition;
@property AVMutableAudioMix *mutableAudioMix;
@property AVAssetExportSession *exportSession;
- (void)performWithAsset : (NSURL *)moviename;
@end

In //viewcontroller.m 

- (void)performWithAsset : (NSURL *)moviename
{

    self.mutableComposition=nil;
    self.mutableVideoComposition=nil;
    self.mutableAudioMix=nil;

//    NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp1.mov"];
//    
//    NSLog(@"file name== %@",filename);
//    
//    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:filename forKey:@"currentName"];
//    NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    // NSLog(@"file number %i",_currentFile);

    // NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    // NSString *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];

    AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:moviename options:nil];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = nil;
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = nil;
    CGAffineTransform t1;
    CGAffineTransform t2;

    AVAssetTrack *assetVideoTrack = nil;
    AVAssetTrack *assetAudioTrack = nil;
    // Check if the asset contains video and audio tracks
    if ([[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] != 0) {
        assetVideoTrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];
    }
    if ([[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count] != 0) {
        assetAudioTrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio][0];
    }

    CMTime insertionPoint = kCMTimeZero;
    NSError *error = nil;


    // Step 1
    // Create a composition with the given asset and insert audio and video tracks into it from the asset
    if (!self.mutableComposition) {

        // Check whether a composition has already been created, i.e, some other tool has already been applied
        // Create a new composition
        self.mutableComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

        // Insert the video and audio tracks from AVAsset
        if (assetVideoTrack != nil) {
            AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [self.mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
            [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:assetVideoTrack atTime:insertionPoint error:&error];
        }
        if (assetAudioTrack != nil) {
            AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [self.mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
            [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [asset duration]) ofTrack:assetAudioTrack atTime:insertionPoint error:&error];
        }

    }


    // Step 2
    // Translate the composition to compensate the movement caused by rotation (since rotation would cause it to move out of frame)
    t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, 0.0);
        float width=assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width;
    float height=assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height;
    float toDiagonal=sqrt(width*width+height*height);
    float toDiagonalAngle = radiansToDegrees(acosf(width/toDiagonal));
    float toDiagonalAngle2=90-radiansToDegrees(acosf(width/toDiagonal));

    float toDiagonalAngleComple;
    float toDiagonalAngleComple2;
    float finalHeight = 0.0;
    float finalWidth = 0.0;

    float degrees=90;

    if(degrees>=0&&degrees<=90){

        toDiagonalAngleComple=toDiagonalAngle+degrees;
        toDiagonalAngleComple2=toDiagonalAngle2+degrees;

        finalHeight=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple)));
        finalWidth=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple2)));

        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(height*sinf(degreesToRadians(degrees)), 0.0);
    }
    else if(degrees>90&&degrees<=180){


        float degrees2 = degrees-90;

        toDiagonalAngleComple=toDiagonalAngle+degrees2;
        toDiagonalAngleComple2=toDiagonalAngle2+degrees2;

        finalHeight=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple2)));
        finalWidth=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple)));

        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(width*sinf(degreesToRadians(degrees2))+height*cosf(degreesToRadians(degrees2)), height*sinf(degreesToRadians(degrees2)));
    }
    else if(degrees>=-90&&degrees<0){

        float degrees2 = degrees-90;
        float degreesabs = ABS(degrees);

        toDiagonalAngleComple=toDiagonalAngle+degrees2;
        toDiagonalAngleComple2=toDiagonalAngle2+degrees2;

        finalHeight=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple2)));
        finalWidth=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple)));

        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, width*sinf(degreesToRadians(degreesabs)));

    }
    else if(degrees>=-180&&degrees<-90){

        float degreesabs = ABS(degrees);
        float degreesplus = degreesabs-90;

        toDiagonalAngleComple=toDiagonalAngle+degrees;
        toDiagonalAngleComple2=toDiagonalAngle2+degrees;

        finalHeight=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple)));
        finalWidth=ABS(toDiagonal*sinf(degreesToRadians(toDiagonalAngleComple2)));

        t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(width*sinf(degreesToRadians(degreesplus)), height*sinf(degreesToRadians(degreesplus))+width*cosf(degreesToRadians(degreesplus)));

    }


    // Rotate transformation
    t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, degreesToRadians(degrees));
    //t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, -90);


    // Step 3
    // Set the appropriate render sizes and rotational transforms
    if (!self.mutableVideoComposition) {

        // Create a new video composition
        self.mutableVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
        // self.mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height,assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.width);
        self.mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(finalWidth,finalHeight);

        self.mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,30);

        // The rotate transform is set on a layer instruction
        instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [self.mutableComposition duration]);
        layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:(self.mutableComposition.tracks)[0]];
        [layerInstruction setTransform:t2 atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    } else {

        self.mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(self.mutableVideoComposition.renderSize.height, self.mutableVideoComposition.renderSize.width);

        // Extract the existing layer instruction on the mutableVideoComposition
        instruction = (self.mutableVideoComposition.instructions)[0];
        layerInstruction = (instruction.layerInstructions)[0];

        // Check if a transform already exists on this layer instruction, this is done to add the current transform on top of previous edits
        CGAffineTransform existingTransform;

        if (![layerInstruction getTransformRampForTime:[self.mutableComposition duration] startTransform:&existingTransform endTransform:NULL timeRange:NULL]) {
            [layerInstruction setTransform:t2 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        } else {
            // Note: the point of origin for rotation is the upper left corner of the composition, t3 is to compensate for origin
            CGAffineTransform t3 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-1*assetVideoTrack.naturalSize.height/2, 0.0);
            CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(existingTransform, CGAffineTransformConcat(t2, t3));
            [layerInstruction setTransform:newTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        }

    }


    // Step 4
    // Add the transform instructions to the video composition
    instruction.layerInstructions = @[layerInstruction];
    self.mutableVideoComposition.instructions = @[instruction];


    // Step 5
    // Notify AVSEViewController about rotation operation completion
    // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AVSEEditCommandCompletionNotification object:self];

    [self performWithAssetExport];
}

- (void)performWithAssetExport
{
    // Step 1
    // Create an outputURL to which the exported movie will be saved

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *outputURL = paths[0];
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [manager createDirectoryAtPath:outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    outputURL = [outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
    // Remove Existing File
    [manager removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];


    // Step 2
    // Create an export session with the composition and write the exported movie to the photo library
    self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:[self.mutableComposition copy] presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1280x720];

    self.exportSession.videoComposition = self.mutableVideoComposition;
    self.exportSession.audioMix = self.mutableAudioMix;
    self.exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];
    self.exportSession.outputFileType=AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;


    [self.exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
        switch (self.exportSession.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:

                //[self playfunction];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"Backhome" object:nil];



                // Step 3
                // Notify AVSEViewController about export completion
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed:%@",self.exportSession.error);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Canceled:%@",self.exportSession.error);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];



}
```

Comment: I was asking why it happens, not how to fix it.